How to observe system value changes in an Android widget
I am creating a widget in an android app and I want to observe the device night mode to check if it is enabled or not in the widget. I want to do that, because in the widget I am displaying an image and I want to show a different one, according to the night mode. Consider that I am forced to use the old way of creating widgets (XML layouts, AppContentProvider etc.) instead of Glance. Is this possible? If it is not is there any similar solution?

I'm not entirely aware of widget api but as far as night mode goes can't you react to "configuration change" and look for "ui mode - night"?

@Pawel There is a method called onAppWidgetOptionsChanged, but it is called when this widget has been layed out at a new size or its options changed via AppWidgetManager. updateAppWidgetOptions. The problem is that I need to observe somehow the value of the night mode status.

Apparently some launchers will notify Widgets about this through onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(), but that's not standard behavior. Also, it should be noted that some newer RemoteViews methods have separate options for night/notNight – e.g., setIcon() – but not until API level 31, so those probably aren't much help right now. The only (technically) reliable way that I can think of is using a foreground Service with…

…Pawel's onConfigurationChanged() suggestion, but nobody likes constantly running Services. Other than that, it may be possible to use WorkManager/JobScheduler with a content URI trigger on the night mode value in the Settings Provider. The relevant value is undocumented, though, so it likely won't work everywhere, but it might be better than nothing. I put together a simple Widget to test my theory, if you wanna give it a try: https://github.com/gonodono/night-widget. It seems to work on all of the current emulators, and recent Samsungs, at least.

Another recent question made me realize that I'd neglected to mention the alternate resource option here. If your images are being loaded from resources, you can put the night image in a directory with the -night qualifier – e.g., res/drawable-night/ – and the correct image should load automatically, as long as the host refreshes its Widgets upon a configuration change.
